# Stored procedure from oracle not returning control to Java application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have java application that uses ojdbc7.jar to connect oracle database.I am calling procedure from my application using CallableStatement. Here, if procedure execution time is more than 60 minutes then control does not return back to application side. We are maintaining procedure execution logs in that it is found that procedure is completed successfully.

Is there any configuration value in oracle database which we can change? Because if procedure execution completed in less than 60 minutes then control automatically return back to application side.

Please suggest.

I tried to check with my DBA but no clue

Comment: No, you'd have to kill the session from another, but that's hardly productive. It sounds like you just need to tune your procedure so it doesn't take so long. If you must continue processing on the app side before the database work is done, then it sounds like you may want to perform the database call in an asynchronous manner and have a callback function handle status-back.

Comment: _"uses ojdbc7.jar"_ are you really still using Java 7? If not, you should use a variant of the Oracle JDBC driver that is closer to your actual Java version.

Comment: Hi Paul, This is sequencial operation. After execution of the procedure the next process continues. And procedure is processing huge amount of data that is why it is taking time.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have tried with ojdbc 8 too. But issue remained same

Answer (score 0):

1. Calling a stored procedure that takes 60 minutes seems like a bad idea.  Either the procedure is in desperate need of being tuned or you really want to have the procedure run asynchronously via a job.
2. What is the error that you get?  The Oracle database is more than happy to wait however long it takes for the procedure to finish.  Application servers and network firewalls, however, often have timeouts that forcibly close database connections if there is no activity for a period of time.  My wager is that there is a firewall between your app server and your database server that forcibly closes connections that it sees as idle for more than 60 minutes.  That's a pretty common firewall timeout period.  The actual error that the Java application is getting would be helpful.

Comment: Dear Justin, Thanks for your answer. The procedure calling block is written in try catch and there is no error message, program execution keeps hanging at callable.execute(). I will check for firewall time out.